# CodeIgniter doesn't show error line or file

Tags: php, codeigniter, numbers, line

CodeIgniter is displaying an error but it doesn't say in what line or what file is the error in. All I get is

> syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Maybe I changed a configuration by accident?

Edit: The problem is not the error, the problem is I don't know where the error is because CodeIgniter suddenly is not showing that information anymore.However the logs are showing the file and error line.

Edit 2: The question is NOT a duplicate. I'm not asking how can I fix this particular error, I'm asking if anyone knows why CodeIgniter is not saying where the error is and is only displaying the error itself.

Comment: Well, check your version control system for recent changes. It's impossible to guess for anyone else too.

Comment: Check your web servers error log and see if you find more info in there.

Comment: Try this on the command line from your root directory, it will help find the exact file: `find . -name \*.php -exec php -l "{}" \;`

Comment: @aynber The problem is not the error, the problem is that is doesn't say where the error is and there are thousands of lines of code.

Comment: In config.php set $config['log_threshold'] to 1 and run your file. There will be a log file generated in 'application/logs/' folder with a date attached.

Comment: @Rishi Yes, that worked. Is a little bit annoying having to check the logs instead of seeing the error on the browser but it's better than nothing. Thanks!